# Run Spyder as a ConEmu tab

Tags: windows, command-line, conemu

Is it possible to run Spyder ([I]Python IDE) inside a ConEmu tab?

I use Notepad++ as an external editor in Far Manager & it runs inside one since I've added -new_console to my external editor command in Far.

I have WinPython installed (by default i.e. as a portable application) & tried to run IPython Notebook.exe inside ConEmu via a hotkey macro like this:

`cmd.exe /k "...\\"IPython Notebook.exe\"" -new_console`

But ipython process runs in a new cmd.exe window instead.

Can anyone advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run `cmd.exe` in ConEmu tab.

Instead you have to run WinPython.

More, `iPython.exe` is a **console** application, but if you want to run python script as [ChildGui](http://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html) you have to run `pythonw.exe` with appropriate arguments.

Comment: Thank you! I realize now that what is wrong with my question, also Spyder.exe launches an additional process (to start IPython kernel? I'm probably using the wrong words here...), so it can't be captured even if started via new console dialog (which works for many other applications)